# Reference specific properties of an object in for loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a `matchCenterItem` object in my Parse cloud code with properties like categoryId, minPrice, etc. What I want to do is iterate through every instance of `matchCenterItem` that a user has, and then reference specific properties of it in the code. So something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {

  var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");  
  for (let i of matchCenterItem) {
         console.log(i.categoryId);
         console.log(i.minPrice);
  }

  success: function (httpResponse) {

          console.log('It worked!');
          response.success('Yay!');

  },
          error: function (httpResponse) {
              console.log('error!!!');
              response.error('Request failed');
          }
});
```

This is obviously wrong, I'm just not sure how to form the syntax to accomplish this correctly.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: @JoeBlow I hadn't even noticed, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to query the class to look at the contents:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {

  var query = new Parse.Query("MatchCenterTest");
  query.limit(10);
  query.find().then(function(results) {
    for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
     console.log(results[i].get('categoryId'));
     console.log(results[i].get('minPrice'));
    }
    response.success('Cool');
  }, function(error) {
    response.error('Uncool');
  });

});
```